# Custom-Made SmartCardReader Problem on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, smartcard

I have a custom made smartCardReader which i wrote it's firmware. Device is working well on Windows, but its problematic on Ubuntu.

I installed necessary tools to test the device. Simply followed the guide [here](https://community.nxp.com/t5/NFC-Knowledge-Base/Installation-of-Linux-CCID-driver-For-NFC-Reader/ta-p/1116321):

- CCID driver from [here](https://ccid.apdu.fr/)
- Opensc-tool
- Pcsc-lite...
- Added my vendorId, productId.. file at `/usr/local/lib/pcsc/drivers/ifd-ccid.bundle/Contents/info.plist`

As a last note my client application works fine with a well known smartcard reader on Ubuntu but not with my custom made smartcard reader.

If I plug-in my smartCard reader and list smartcardreaders on terminal by `opensc-tool -l` command, i can see my smartcard reader. I can read ATR with `opensc-tool -a` command.

I want to view all logs about the communication made between smartcard reader and PC. So as written in [here](https://ccid.apdu.fr/) after i kill any running pcscd process i restart pcscd exactly as `sudo LIBCCID_ifdLogLevel=0x000F pcscd --foreground --debug --apdu --color | tee log.txt`.

But after this command if i list smartcard readers with `opensc-tool -l` command it says something like `No smartcard readers found.`.

Why?

What would be the reason of this device working well on Windows but not Ubuntu?

Is there any better tool for diagnose smartcard reader problems on Ubuntu?

Thanks.